# change gem environment settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, rubygems, environment

I'm setting up a bunch of things on aws. I need to install gem and compass and node.
The thing is, previously my gem on another aws instance, it shows its installation as:

RubyGems Environment:

1. List item
2. RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
3. RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [x86_64-linux]
4. INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0
5. RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.0
6. EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/bin
7. SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.gem/specs
8. RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

   - ruby
   - x86_64-linux
9. GEM PATHS:

   - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0
   - /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0
   - /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0
10. GEM CONFIGURATION:

    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
11. REMOTE SOURCES:

    - https://rubygems.org/
12. SHELL PATH:

    - /usr/local/bin
    - /bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/local/sbin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /sbin
    - /opt/aws/bin
    - /home/ec2-user/bin

But when I tried to launch a new instance and tried to install compass. (compass is fine) but the node can't be installed and i think it's the gem environment problem that the native can't be found. Cause now the gem's environment settings are:

1. RubyGems Environment:

   1. RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
   2. RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
   3. INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8
   4. RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
   5. EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
   6. SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.gem/specs
   7. RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

      - ruby
      - x86_64-linux
   8. GEM PATHS:

      - /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8
      - /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/1.8
   9. GEM CONFIGURATION:

      - :update_sources => true
      - :verbose => true
      - :backtrace => false
      - :bulk_threshold => 1000
   10. REMOTE SOURCES:

       - https://rubygems.org/
   11. SHELL PATH:

       - /usr/local/bin
       - /bin
       - /usr/bin
       - /usr/local/sbin
       - /usr/sbin
       - /sbin
       - /opt/aws/bin
       - /usr/bin/ant/bin
       - /home/ec2-user/bin
   12. List item

Is there a way to fix it or change the gem environment settings?

Thanks!